# Adding SOAP Envelope to ElementTree generated XML

Tags: python, xml, soap

I have read some data from a database, and using `xml.etree.ElementTree` I am able to generate XML using this code:

```
top = ET.Element("Enquiry")
child = ET.SubElement(top, 'DocumentHeader')

msgid = ET.SubElement(child, 'msgid')
msgid.text = "4444444"

refno = ET.SubElement(child, 'refno')
refno.text = "xxxxxx"

msg_func = ET.SubElement(child, 'msg_func')
msg_func.text = "9"

#...

tree = ET.ElementTree(top)
root = tree.getroot()
data = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
print data
```

This produces this XML:

```
<Enquiry>
   <DocumentHeader>
         <msgid></msgid>
              <refno>UCR201700043926</refno>
              <msg_func>9</msg_func>
              <sender>TIS</sender>
              <receiver>CPS</receiver>
               <version>1</version>
              </DocumentHeader>
         <DocumentDetails>
                  <ucr_no>xxxxxxx</ucr_no>
                  <token>xxxxxx</token>
        </DocumentDetails>
</Enquiry>
```

Now I need to enclose the XML in a SOAP envelope before posting it to a web service using requests. How do I make my XML look the same as this:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.ucr.oga.kesws.crimsonlogic.com/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <web:ucrValidation>
             <arg0><![CDATA[
                <UCR_Enquiry>
                    <DocumentHeader>
                        <msgid></msgid>
                        <refno>xxxxxx</refno>
                        <msg_func>9</msg_func>
                        <sender>SGI</sender>
                        <receiver>CPS</receiver>
                        <version>1</version>
                    </DocumentHeader>
                    <DocumentDetails>
                        <ucr_no>xxx</ucr_no>
                        <token>xxxxxx</token>
                    </DocumentDetails>
                </UCR_Enquiry>
            ]]></arg0>
          </web:ucrValidation>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this later.

```
    data = '''
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.ucr.oga.kesws.crimsonlogic.com/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <web:ucrValidation>
             <arg0><![CDATA[
             {0}
            ]]></arg0>
          </web:ucrValidation>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>'''
```

I used the `.format(d)` function

my `d` being the `XML` generated by `d = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')` 
while posting i just called
 `requests.post(url, data=data.format(d), headers=headers, verify=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Python's standard `ElementTree` library doesn't support CDATA sections, so you'll need to make sure you're using `lxml`. Assuming you already have your `<Enquiry>` element saved as a string, this will give you what you're looking for:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

SOAP_NS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
WEB_NS = 'http://webservice.ucr.oga.kesws.crimsonlogic.com/'
ns_map = {'soapenv': SOAP_NS, 'web': WEB_NS}

env = ET.Element(ET.QName(SOAP_NS, 'Envelope'), nsmap=ns_map)
head = ET.SubElement(env, ET.QName(SOAP_NS, 'Header'), nsmap=ns_map)
body = ET.SubElement(env, ET.QName(SOAP_NS, 'Body'), nsmap=ns_map)
val = ET.SubElement(body, ET.QName(WEB_NS, 'ucrValidation'), nsmap=ns_map)
arg = ET.SubElement(val, 'arg0')
arg.text = ET.CDATA('Here is where you can put your CDATA text!!!')

# now you have XML!
print(ET.tostring(env, pretty_print=True))
```

I use the `QName` function to create the element names including the namespace URI. The namespace map passed to `Element` and `SubElement` (another `lxml` extension) maps that URI to a prefix, which is used for the output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.ucr.oga.kesws.crimsonlogic.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:ucrValidation>
      <arg0><![CDATA[Here is where you can put your CDATA text!!!]]></arg0>
    </web:ucrValidation>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```